# Not sure if logic is correct when looping

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

So what I want to do is generate an ID for every new user. It'll be unique. S

```
    function generateRandomString($length = 8) {
        $characters = '0123456789';
        $randomString = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
        }
        return $randomString;
    }
```

Now here's what I'm doing in total

```
//Generate truly unique ID
function generateRandomString($length = 8) {
    $characters = '0123456789';
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

$unid = generateRandomString();

//Check if ID OG
$idog = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = :uid");
$idog->bindValue(':uid', $unid);
$idog->execute();

//Loop if ID not OG
while ($idog->rowCount() > 0) {
    function generateRandomString($length = 8) {
        $characters = '0123456789';
        $randomString = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
        }
        return $randomString;
    }
}
$unid = generateRandomString();
```

Now I'd assume that this would keep looping as long as the ID is taken. I couldn't test it, simply because it would take a while. So basically my question is, is the logic right? Will it keep looping until a new ID is generated? Is there a more effective way to do this?

Comment: You comment (`//Generate truly unique ID`) is a lie. Also check out the docs about user defined functions http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Comment: A more effective way is to use a primary key for the users table with auto increment. So the database management system will assign a unique integer value to each new record, incrementing the counter by one. Also your code is vulnerable to race conditions if you execute it in parallel as is the case for web applications. This can be solved by making the field unique in the database.

Comment: You know there is a easier way to generate a random string, you know? Make an array with the characters (array_range() will help you), use array_shuffle(), implode() and then substr().

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you need to have a random string as the id? Since you tagged mysql, I am assuming that is your database, so why don't you just insert the user into the table and then do this query "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()". This assumes that the "id" column is an "AUTO_INCREMENT" value. Note, you will need to wrap the insert and the call for for the last inserted id in a transaction to guarantee the id returned was from the insert you just performed.

I realize your question was whether your logic was correct, but it feels as though you are trying to re-invent the wheel here. Use the features of a database already given to you.